# Connecting 2 classes

Tags: java

I have a student object class and I have to create an arraylist of these students.
Im trying to create the program that inputs information into the student object then store it into an arraylist.

The first command to this array is to add a student object to the array the next command would be to remove a student from the array.

How would I get a user to input a command then go to another method that leads to storing information if everytime i try to complie i get static errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CollegeTester
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Student> array = new ArrayList<Student>();
CollegeTester collegeTester = new CollegeTester();;

public static void  main(String[] args)
{
    new CollegeTester().getCommand();
}

public void getCommand()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
    String command = input.nextLine();
    if(command.equals("add"))
        collegeTester.addCommand();
}

public void addCommand()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a Name: ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
}
```

}

Comment: Paste full class and which error is thrown ?

Comment: _"How would I get a user to input ... if everytime i try to complie i get static errors"_ Fix the error!

Comment: that is the full class i have so far because of the errors.

Comment: Error: Main method is not static in class CollegeTester, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

if i change it to a static the error would be 
error: non-static variable input cannot be referenced from a static context
  String command = input.nextLine();

and
error: non-static method addCommand() cannot be referenced from a static context
   addCommand();

Comment: You need to import Student as well or package the classes together

Comment: Student is in the same directory i don't think i need to?

Comment: You need to unless they are in the same package not directory.

Comment: how would i even import the class if the student class is called Student.java

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you call:         collegeTester.addCommand(); ?

Comment: @ addcommand Ill ask the user for name and address and store it into student object and store the object into the array.

Comment: Your `addCommand()` asks for input, assigns it to a String variable, then exits which deletes the String variable you just created and assigned. It is effectively doing nothing.

Comment: Student student = new Student(name);
After i get the name I was going to store it in the student object

Answer (score 0):

There is another loophole. Your main method is not static. Your program will not run without it. Change it to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

}
```

Also then you cannot access non-static methods directly from static method. 
Either you should instantiate class and then call methods or make methods static.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 CollegeTester collegeTester = new CollegeTester();
 collegeTester.addCommand();
 }
```

If you want to call specific method on specific options, then you should use `switch case`.

Answer (score 0):

You  are trying to access to not static method from static method. At first make an instance of CollegeTester class, than call it. For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollegeTester {
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<Student> array = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CollegeTester().getCommand();
    }

    public void getCommand() {
        System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
        String command = input.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("add"))
            this.addCommand();
    }

    public void addCommand() {
        System.out.println("Enter a Name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
    }
}

public class Student {
    // Some properties and fty.
}
```

Comment: So I propose that it exists. OK, I will add it provided code to make it more clear.

Comment: I don't get this method.

Comment: Which method you mean, @Shimy?

Comment: at CollegeTester.<init>(CollegeTester.java:8)
Spam of this error appears

Comment: Strange, I run it in, and it work. Please provide all error stack.

Comment: Pleas at firs copy paste my code and run, then compare with your to get the difference.

Comment: OK, try debug it, and say in what row it throw exception, and provide at least first line of exception.

Comment: I see you edited your code, and I got the same error running your code. You are making the class recursively.Make the following change.

 static CollegeTester collegeTester;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        collegeTester = new CollegeTester();
        collegeTester.getCommand();
    }

Comment: BTW, you can make the code more simpler, using "this" instead of "collegeTester" variable, and not creating this property even. And in main just write "new CollegeTester().getCommand();"